# "Look like" used for describing the similarity in structures

Tags: phrase-choice

> The word "hop" looks like a sandwich: the consonants are like the
>   bread, the vowel is like the ham.

Is it correct to use "look like" for describing the inner structure of a thing similar to another one (not the physical resemblance) or only "be like" is acceptable? In other words, can "look like" and "be like" be used interchangeably in some contexts?

Answer (score 1):

"Look**s** like" is correct.

Not "be like" or "look like".